# How to determine the position of a node based on the value

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am trying to get the position of a node based on its value, so that I can then get corresponding entries.

Here is the source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sampleSourceXML>
    <Table>
        <Header>
            <Column>Name</Column>
            <Column>Surname</Column>
            <Column>Title</Column>
        </Header>
        <Body>
            <Row>
                <Entry>James</Entry>
                <Entry>Bond</Entry>
                <Entry>Mr</Entry>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Entry>Harry</Entry>
                <Entry>Potter</Entry>
                <Entry>Mr</Entry>
            </Row>
        </Body>
    </Table>
</sampleSourceXML>
```

This is the resulting XML that I would like to achieve:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sampleResultXML>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>James</FirstName>
        <LastName>Bond</LastName>
        <Title>Mr</Title>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>Harry</FirstName>
        <LastName>Potter</LastName>
        <Title>Mr</Title>
    </Person>
</sampleResultXML>
```

I tried it with this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="sampleResultXML">
            <xsl:for-each select="sampleSourceXML/Table/Rows/Row">
                <xsl:element name="Person">
                    <xsl:element name="FirstName">
                        <xsl:value-of select="./Entry[1]/text()"></xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="LastName">
                        <xsl:value-of select="./Entry[2]/text()"></xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="Title">
                        <xsl:value-of select="./Entry[3]/text()"></xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works.

But the source XML can have a different order. For example the Title element can be above the Name element. So the hardcoded position in my XSLT (e.g. Entry[3]) will not work any more.

The header order and the entry order are always corresponding. So if the Column Title is in position 3, so will be the corresponding row.

So I need a way to get the position of, let's say, the Title element dynamically. So I have to go through the Column elements until I reach the one with value "Title". This position I thought I'd save in a variable (e.g. Position_Title) so that I can fill the value later like so:

```
<xsl:element name="Title">
  <xsl:value-of select="./Entry[$Position_Title]/text()"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:element>
```

However I haven't been able to find a way to do this.

Do you have any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I need a way to get the position of, let's say, the Title element dynamically. So I have to go through the Column elements until I reach the one with value "Title". This position I thought I'd save in a variable (e.g. Position_Title) so that I can fill the value later like so:

I think it could be much simpler if you do it from the opposite direction. Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/sampleSourceXML">
    <xsl:variable name="cols" select="Table/Header/Column" />
    <sampleResultXML>
        <xsl:for-each select="Table/Body/Row">
            <Person>
                <xsl:for-each select="Entry">
                    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
                    <xsl:element name="{$cols[$i]}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </Person>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </sampleResultXML>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a ton! I tweaked it a little, so that I can set my own names, but I don't know how long this would have taken me without you!

Comment: I would look for a way to replace the original names with the ones you want **once** and store the result in the `$cols` variable.